# Chromecast receiver "unavailable" on localhost

Tags: chromecast

I have followed the steps here:

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers

and am using this sample sender code:
https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-chrome

to get started creating a chromecast receiver app. I have my app id and when I change the sample to use my app id it returns "unavailable" in the receiverListener event. When I use the default media receiver app id it works just fine.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Where are you serving your receiver from? What type of url are you using (name based or ip address)?

Comment: I am using the styled media receiver.

Not sure how a url matters here.

Comment: You said it is unavailable on "localhost", what does that mean?